# How to make plastic badges?

Tags: plastic

Anyone know how these are made at the gym I think they use a gym but how is it made ?

[image: Badge image]

Comment: Do you need them specifically for identification only or do you need a card printer with mag strips and RFID chips?

Comment: For high volume operations, there are whole systems that print and laminate.  For low volumes, you can use any printer and any laminating machine.  You can buy sheets of micro-perf cards.  You print the insert, stick it into a pre-formed laminating pocket, and run it through the laminating machine.  The pockets can be pre-punched with the hole, or you punch the hole with a paper punch.  The pre-formed pockets have rounded corners.  On high-volume machines, a whole sheet of cards is printed and laminated, then the individual cards are punched out with a shaped punch.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing may have been constructed at the gym, but they would have used a device available to anyone. It's likely called a badge laminating machine or some combination of those terms.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008KAK5TS) sells a number of designs encompassing various size capacities.
[image: laminating machine]

This is just one of many available. This particular model has a production restriction in that you cannot produce too many in too short of a period. If you exceed the limit, it's likely the machine will overheat and damage something internally.

More expensive models will have higher production capacity.

Comment: How does it work is there a laser or something ? @fred_dot_u

Comment: The experience I have with this type of product was for identification badges. The printer is fed with blank (white) cards and printed using dye sublimation method. Once completed, a final pass with a protective cover is made to seal in the colors and protect from scratches. If the product information does not state how the cards are printed, ask the seller.